# Converting JAXBElement<String> to json using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Have a class as follows-

```
public class Org{
    @XmlElementRef(name = "InstitutionCode", namespace = "http://schemas.tes.org/2004/07/ABC.test", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
        protected JAXBElement<String> institutionCode;      
        }
```

Using Jackson converting the object org to JSON

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JAXBElement<String> code = 
            new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("http://schemas.tes.org/2004/07/ABC.test", "institutionCode"), String.class, "inst");
    Organization org = new Organization();

    org.setInstitutionCode(code);

       String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(org);
    System.out.println(jsonInString);
```

get the value as

```
  {"institutionCode":{"Name":"{http://schemas.tes.org/2004/07/ABC.test}institutionCode"}
```

How to get the value as

```
{"institutionCode":"inst"}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom Jackson serializer for it:

```
public class OrgSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Org> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Org org, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("institutionCode", org.getInstitutionCode());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then, you can annotate the class to use the serializer:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = OrgSerializer.class)
public class Org {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you don't want this every time, or you can't change the class, you can pass the class as a parameter to the `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Org.class, new OrgSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

---

Another solution coud be using `@JsonView`, but I haven't used that myself.

Comment: Thanks meskobalazs, but the class org is a generated class and I cant change it. Is there another way to apply custom Jackson serializer

Comment: Thanks a lot meskobalazs.